# How to pass freemarker email template as email in Liferay?

Tags: java, email, liferay, freemarker

I have used Freemarker for creating a template which I will be using to send as email.
Here is the snippet of the parameters that i wish to include in the template.
Iam using java..

//use freemarker
            Configuration config = new Configuration();
            config.setTemplateLoader(new ClassTemplateLoader(getClass(), "/"));

```
        Template template = config.getTemplate("helloworld.ftl");

        // Build the data-model
        Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        data.put("message", "Hello!! You have got a new approval mail!");

        //List parsing 
        List<String> mailDetails = new ArrayList<String>();
        mailDetails.add(fromAddress);
        mailDetails.add(fromName);
        mailDetails.add(toAddress);
        mailDetails.add(toName);
        mailDetails.add(subject);
        mailDetails.add(body);

        data.put("mailDetails", mailDetails);


        // Console output
        Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(System.out);
        template.process(data, out);
        out.flush();
```

This is tested and it successfully created a template in the specified folder.
All I want to know is how do i pass the template that is generated as a parameter while sending mail?

I am sending email as follows in Liferay
How should I pass the template as a parameter while sending mail?

Comment: Where is your Freemarker template? Also, I can't imagine you won't have problems storing your parameters in a list, as opposed to a map.

Comment: I have edited my post. pl check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're writing to `System.out`

```
    // Console output
    Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(System.out);
    template.process(data, out);
    out.flush();
```

You can write to a String:

```
    StringWriter out = new StringWriter();
    template.process(data, out);
    String finishedMessage = out.toString();
```

or pass any other writer to the `process()` method.

Comment: Thanks Nathaniel. I have accepted your answer. It worked.. :)